# The composer install and update error in laravel 4.2

Tags: macos, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm trying to make composer install and the result

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1 
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.17
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.2.17
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.16
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.2.16
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.15
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.2.12
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.14
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.2.9
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.13
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.2.8
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v5.0.33
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.12
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.2.7
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v5.0.28
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.11
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.2.6
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v5.0.26
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.10
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.2.5
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v5.0.25
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.9
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.2.4
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v5.0.22
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.8
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v4.2.3
- Installation request for wicochandra/captcha 1.1.1 -> satisfiable by wicochandra/captcha[1.1.1].
- Installation request for latrell/captcha dev-master -> satisfiable by latrell/captcha[dev-master].
- Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.13, v4.2.14, v4.2.15, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
- wicochandra/captcha 1.1.1 requires illuminate/support 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.13, v4.2.14, v4.2.15, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9], illuminate/support[v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.2.1].
- Can only install one of: illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v4.2.2].
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.1
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.2
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.3
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.4
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.5
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.6
- don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4.2.7
- latrell/captcha dev-master requires illuminate/support 5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4
```

and When make the update

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
```

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.3
    - Installation request for latrell/captcha dev-master -> satisfiable by latrell/captcha[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.1
    - latrell/captcha dev-master requires illuminate/support 5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.1.8, v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.4, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.6].
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0|remove illuminate/support v5.1.8
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.22
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.25
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.26
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.28
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.33
    - don't install laravel/framework v4.2.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.13, v4.2.14, v4.2.15, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
```

the composer.json

```
  {
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "way/generators": "~2.0",
    "intervention/image": "~1.5",
    "latrell/captcha": "dev-master",
    "wicochandra/captcha": "1.1.1",
    "thujohn/pdf": "dev-master"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
 },
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- latrell/captcha dev-master requires illuminate/support 5.*
```

This is the reason for your failure. You are trying to use that package, which depends on Laravel 5, while trying to install Laravel 4 at the same time.

I'd suggest you never edit the `composer.json` manually, but run this simple command line instead:

```
composer require latrell/captcha
```

This will check packagist.org and install the most recent, installable version for you. If it cannot install one, it will tell you instantly.

When you want to require a specific version, the command will accept a version parameter as well:

```
composer require latrell/captcha:~1.0
```

While in general it is a very bad idea to use branches, they would work instead of a version as well.

The reason they are bad is: You might have once added the master branch to your project, and the past version of it was compatible to Laravel 4. But this branch has changed, and now the master branch is incompatible. You are now forever unable to run `composer update`, because it is very unlikely that the branch will again become compatible. Always try to use a tagged version. If the software you want to use does not have releases tagged: Ask the maintainer to tag a release - even alpha stability would help. If the maintainer does not want to tag a release: Leave their software alone, using it will harm your project more long term than it is worth it.

Alternatively: Fork the project and tag the software yourself. But essentially this means you take over responsibility to maintain your fork, even if it would be only for your local development, and nobody else. You'd have to track the progress of the original project - otherwise you'll end up with one stale version, horribly out of sync with the original source, with a huge effort needed to update it once again.

Avoid using branches.